# Angular2 Second component not appearing

Tags: angular

I'm in the documentation *User Input*.  At the bottom of the page is *little-tour.component.ts*.  It has a selector of *'little-tour'*

I tried creating that file and adding under app, and then going to index.html and adding a selector for it,

```
 <body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
<little-tour>One Moment...</little-tour>
```

I then went to app.module.ts and added

```
import { LittleTourComponent } from './little-tour.component';
```

as well as

```
  declarations: [ AppComponent, LittleTourComponent ],
```

all I get is my place holder (One Moment...) - the Angular code is not running.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key problem is that I had my tag

```
<little-tour>One Moment...</little-tour>
```

inside index.html rather than inside the template in app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

In `<body>` only components are created that you bootstrap

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports:      [BrowserModule],
    bootstrap:    [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```